# No route matches [POST] "/organizations/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I got quite a few resources and have created a few forms already - but for some reason I don't seem to get one specific form for a new object to work. I am not sure if it is because I am using a three-way has_many :through relationship or because I am just overlooking something else

Here's how my routes looks like

```
  resources :users, shallow: true do
    resources :organizations, :notifications
  end

  resources :organizations, shallow: true do
    resources :plans, :users, :notifications
  end
```

My organizations_controller looks like this:

```
 def index
    @user = current_user
    @organizations = @user.organizations.to_a
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @organization = Organization.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
    @organization.save
    redirect_to @organization
  end
```

On my organizations index page I link to this:

```
<%= button_to 'New Organization', new_organization_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

which should lead to my new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for (@organization) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :website %>
      <%= f.text_area :website, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
    <%= f.button :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Every time I click on "new Organization" I get following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/organizations/new"
```

Which is correct - I do not have a new_organizations_path that accepts POST requests. I know I can manually change the method of the form to GET but shouldn't it work the way I did it? I have another form that follows the same principle just for a different resource and it works perfectly.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button_to` would always send a `POST` request unless something else is specified. 
On the other form, you must be using `link_to` and not `button_to` which is why its working there.

You can change the `button_to` in two ways, pick the one that suits you:

### Option 1: Use link_to

```
<%= link_to 'New Organization', new_organization_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

### Option 2: Use button_to with method: :get

```
<%= button_to 'New Organization', new_organization_path, method: :get, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Comment: You are my personal hero from now on. I knew it was something simple and looked for hours trying to figure it out!